# How do I update an array from MongoDB document that match a certain value?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'm a new mongoDB user, and I'm confused on how to update my document.

I have this document:

```
"_id" : ObjectId("5674c86aba97df0800995da7"),
"role" : "tutor",
"schools" : [ 
    "CHIJ Our Lady Of Good Counsel",
    "Nanyang Technological University"]
```

And I'd like to update the schools array from this document that matches a certain value from a var. I've tried like this:

```
var schools = [{ "name": "Nanyang Technological University (NTU)", "value": "nanyang-technological-university-(ntu)" }];

db.getCollection('clients').update(
// query
{
    "schools" : schools.name
},

// update
{

    $set:{"schools":[schools.value]}
},

// options
{
    "multi" : true,  // update only one document
    "upsert" : false  // insert a new document, if no existing document match the query
}
);
```

But of course, it's not working. Can anyone help me with this? Thanks!

I need the document to be displaying this value after update:

```
"_id" : ObjectId("5674c86aba97df0800995da7"),
"role" : "tutor",
"schools" : [ 
    "CHIJ Our Lady Of Good Counsel",
    "nanyang-technological-university-(ntu)"]
```

Comment: Can you please post an expected output for your problem?

Comment: Sure. I have updated the question with expected output. Thanks @BatScream

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make use of the [`$`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/update/positional/#up._S_) operator:

- for each item in the `schools` variable,
- `find` records, with the corresponding `name` in the `schools` array field.
- `$set` the new `value` at the position of the matched `name` using the `$` positional operator.

code:

```
var schools=[{"name":"Nanyang Technological University", 
              "value":"nanyang-technological-university-(ntu)"}];


schools.forEach(function(i){
  db.clients.update({"schools.name":i.name},
            {$set:{"schools.$":i.value}},
            {"multi":true})
})
```